# Implementation of a shared pointer constructors and destructor

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management, pointers

I am writing my simple shared pointer. I am asking to review existing functions (understand that my implementations is not full, e.g now `operator*`)

Review please correctness

1. Copy/move constructors and operator=
2. Destructors

My code

```
template<typename T>
class my_shared_ptr {
public:
    my_shared_ptr() {}

    my_shared_ptr(T* ptr) {
        ptr_ = ptr;
        counter_ = new size_t(1);
    }

    my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& other) {
        destroy_current();
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        if (other.ptr_ != nullptr) {
            *counter_ += 1;
        }
    }

    my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& other) {
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
        other.counter_ = nullptr;
    }

    my_shared_ptr& operator=(const my_shared_ptr& other) {
        destroy_current();
        
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        if (other.ptr_ != nullptr) {
            *counter_ += 1;
        }
    }

    my_shared_ptr&& operator=(my_shared_ptr&& other) {
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
        other.counter_ = nullptr;
    }

    ~my_shared_ptr() {
        destroy_current();
    }
private:
    void destroy_current() {
        if (counter_ and *counter_ > 1) {
            *counter_ -= 1;
        } else {
            delete ptr_;
            delete counter_;
        }
    }
private:
    T* ptr_ = nullptr;
    size_t* counter_ = nullptr;
};


template<typename T, typename... Args>
my_shared_ptr<T> make_my_shared(Args&&... args) {
    auto ptr = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return my_shared_ptr<T>(ptr);
}


struct A {
  int val_ = 0;
  A(int val) : val_(val) { std::cout << "A(" << val_ << ")" << std::endl ; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "~A(" << val_ << ")" << std::endl ; }

};


int main() {
  std::cout << "-----------\n";
  {
    my_shared_ptr<A> a1;
    //my_shared_ptr<A> a2 = make_my_shared<A>(2); 
    my_shared_ptr<A> a2(new A(2));
    {
      my_shared_ptr<A> a3(new A(3));
      std::cout << "log 1" << std::endl;
      a1 = a3;
      std::cout << "log 2" << std::endl;
      a2 = a3;
      std::cout << "log 3" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "log 4" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "Program finished!" << std::endl ;

}
```

Comment: I cannot call this a shared pointer because the counter and destruction are not thread-safe. You cannot use it in multi-threaded context.

Comment: @ALX23z Shared pointers are useful in a single-threaded context as well. But you are right in the sense that `std::shared_ptr` has some level of thread-safety.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: Indeed; and it could be useful to implement a `single_thread_shared_ptr` for performance reasons, so ref counting can use cheap non-atomic operations, since ISO C++ doesn't have that; if you use `shared_ptr`, you get atomic RMW operations.  So the problem here is the naming, not the lack of thread-safety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Overview

Self assignment is broken.

### Code Review

First issue is here:

```
    my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& other) {

        // You are creating this object for the first time
        // So there is never going to be anything to destroy.
        destroy_current();
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        if (other.ptr_ != nullptr) {
            *counter_ += 1;
        }
    }
```

---

You really want move semantics to be exception safe.
I don't see any reason why it could not be exception safe.

```
    my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& other) {
    // So this function should be marked as noexcept.
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        
        // There is already a command to set and move (see: std::exchange)
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
        other.counter_ = nullptr;
    }
```

---

This is actually broken.

Self assignment is going to release the memory, then increment the pointer on the newly released counter.

```
    my_shared_ptr& operator=(const my_shared_ptr& other) {
        destroy_current();
        
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        if (other.ptr_ != nullptr) {
            *counter_ += 1;
        }
    }
```

Try:

```
    my_shared_ptr<int>  first(new int{4});
    my_shared_ptr<int>& ref = first;

    first = ref; // bang.
```

---

Again. This should probably be exception safe. So mark it as such. Aslo you can use `std::exchange()` to do most of the work.

```
    my_shared_ptr&& operator=(my_shared_ptr&& other) {
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
        other.counter_ = nullptr;
    }
```

### How I would write it:

```
template<typename T>
class my_shared_ptr
{
     T            ptr   = nullptr;
     std::size_t* size  = nullptr;


     bool decrementCountReachedZero() const
     {
         --(*size);
         return *size == 0;
     }

     public:
         ~my_shared_ptr()
         {
             if (size && decrementCountReachedZero()) {
                 delete ptr;
                 delete size;
             }
         }

         // Note: Default constructor
         //       Uses the default initialization values.
         my_shared_ptr() {}

         // Take ownership of a pointer.
         explicit my_shared_ptr(T* take)
             : ptr(take)
             , size(new std::size_t{1})
         {}

         // You may want a constructor that takes a `nullptr`
         // Because the above will not allow nullptr because of
         // the explicit
         my_shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t)
             : ptr(nullptr)
             , size(nullptr)
         {}

         // Standard Copy Constructor.
         my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr const& copy)
             : ptr(copy.ptr)
             , size(copy.size)
         {
             // OK we have constructed now.
             // So increment the size if it exists
             if (size) {
                ++(*size);
             }
         }

         // Standard Move Constructor
         my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& move) noexcept
             : ptr(std::exchange(move.ptr, nullptr))
             , size(std::exchange(move.size, nullptr))
         {
             // No action required
             // as original objects pointers have been set to null
             // Thus effectively transferring ownership of any
             // pointer.
         }


         // NOTE HERE
         //
         // I am writing both the copy and move assignment
         // operators out in full. This is NOT the best way
         // to do it. I am doing this to help illustrate the
         // correct way. (See below)

         // For normal copy assignment.
         // Use the copy and swap idiom.
         my_shared_ptr& operator=(my_shared_ptr const& copy)
         {
             my_shared_ptr tmp{copy};            // increment of any counters
                                                 // happens in the copy.
                                                 // decrement of any counters
                                                 // happens when this object
                                                 // is destroyed (which will not
                                                 // be the same as the object created :-)

             // Do the work.
             // Swap the tmp and the current object.
             // everything should be in the correct place.
             tmp.swap(*this);
             return *this;
         }
     
         // For normal move assignment.
         // Make sure the current object owned by "this" is destroyed.
         // Overwrite "this" one and set "move" old version to nullptr.
         my_shared_ptr& operator=(my_shared_ptr&& move) noexcept
         {
             my_shared_ptr tmp{std::move(*this)};// This moves the current object
                                                 // into a temp. This will be
                                                 // destroyed at end of scope
                                                 // and thus reduce the counter
                                                 // if there is one.


             // Do the work.
             // The current object is now null
             // So we swap with the source("move") thus putting nulls
             // into "move" and setting this object with the new value.
             move.swap(*this);
             return *this;
         }

         // NOTE: You will notice that both versions of
         //       the assignment operator are identical.
         // So there is a neat trick to simplify both these
         // into a single assignment operator that handles
         // both situations:

         // Simply pass by value.
         // If it is an lvalue it is copied.
         // If it is an rvalue it will be moved.
         // Which has the identical operation as the tmp variable
         my_shared_ptr& operator=(my_shared_ptr tmp) noexcept
         {
             tmp.swap(*this);
             return *this;
         }
         // At this point tmp goes out of scope.
         // destroying the tmp copy or the old value
        


         // Utility function.
         void swap(my_shared_ptr& other) noexcept
         {
             std::swap(ptr,  other.ptr);
             std::swap(size, other.size);
         }
         friend void swap(my_shared_ptr& lhs, my_shared_ptr& rhs)
         {
              lhs.swap(rhs);
         }
};
```

Comment: Great review (and I see I failed to make my answer's move constructor `noexcept`, though I remembered it on `swap()`).

Comment: Great review. Thank you!

Comment: Are there advantages of using initializer list in constructor?

Comment: Why do you use temporary object in operator= ?

Comment: `Are there advantages of using initializer list in constructor?`: Yes. If you don't then objects will be defult constructed. So by default you should use them to form good habit. In C++ the most common way to change an object is to simply change the type so assume that it will have a default constructor at some point at you will always contruct the most effecient method by using initializer list.

Comment: `Why do you use temporary object in operator=` I don't. In the example I set up I demonstrate the long way to do it. In the proper way we pass by value to avoid the need for an actual temporary. **BUT** the technique is called the **Copy and Swap Idiom**

Answer (score 7):

We're missing includes of `<cstddef>` and `<utility>`, and `std::size_t` is misspelt throughout.

Even with those fixed, the code isn't even valid, as neither `operator=` returns a value.  They should both return `*this` as an lvalue-reference (*not* an rvalue-reference).

I'm not a big fan of using the trailing-underscore to differentiate member variables - if you have so many that a separate naming scheme is required, it's usually a sign that a class has multiple responsibilities.

The constructor that takes a raw pointer should be declared `explicit`, as implicit conversion could cause the target to be deleted when we didn't expect that.

Constructors should be using their initializer lists to populate data members, rather than default-initialising then assigning.

Copy-constructor, move-constructor and move-assignment are not exercised in the test program.  Neither is the `make_my_shared()` function.

If I were writing this, I would use swap for the move constructor, and copy-and-swap to implement the assignment operators.  That neatly avoids the bug where self-assignment resets the pointer to null.

```
    my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& other)
    {
        swap(other);
    }

    my_shared_ptr& operator=(my_shared_ptr other)
    {
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(my_shared_ptr& other)
    {
        std::swap(ptr_, other.ptr_);
        std::swap(counter_, other.counter_);
    }
```

Instead of writing `+= 1` and `-= 1`, most C++ programmers would expect to see `++` and `--`.  Similarly, explicit comparison to `nullptr` looks cluttered - often the sign of a Java programmer.

`destroy_current` is over-wordy.  It can be simplified:

```
    void destroy_current()
    {
        if (counter_ && !--*counter_) {
            delete ptr_;
            delete counter_;
        }
    }
```

If that's too terse, then a middle ground might be

```
    void destroy_current()
    {
        if (!counter_) { return; } // null-pointer
        --*counter_;
        if (counter_ == 0) {
            // this was the last reference
            delete ptr_;
            delete counter_;
        }
    }
```

I don't like the way that `destroy_current` leaves the object in an invalid state (with pointers to `delete`d memory).  That means that every use needs to be inspected to ensure it fixes the class invariant (i.e. those pointers are either both null or both point to valid objects).  That said, once we use copy-and-swap and remove its pointless call from the copy constructor, it's only used in one location (the destructor), so we should just inline it there.

We're missing any support for array type as `T`, but nothing to prevent it either.  If we choose to support arrays, we'll need to be use `new[]` and `delete[]`.

It seems that no attempt has been made to consider thread safety in these methods - concurrent modification of `other` will result in unpredictable (possibly undefined) behaviour.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

// N.B. still not thread-safe
// T must be a simple object type - not array
template<typename T>
class my_shared_ptr
{
    T* ptr = nullptr;
    std::size_t* counter = nullptr;

public:
    my_shared_ptr()
    {}

    explicit my_shared_ptr(T* ptr)
        : ptr{ptr},
          counter{new std::size_t{1}}
    {
    }

    my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& other)
        : ptr{other.ptr},
          counter{other.counter}
    {
        if (counter) {
            ++*counter;
        }
    }

    my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& other)
    {
        swap(other);
    }

    my_shared_ptr& operator=(my_shared_ptr other)
    {
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }

    ~my_shared_ptr()
    {
        if (counter && !--*counter) {
            delete ptr;
            delete counter;
        }
    }

    void swap(my_shared_ptr& other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(ptr, other.ptr);
        std::swap(counter, other.counter);
    }
};
```

Comment: Sure: `explicit comparison to nullptr looks cluttered` but this is overkill `if (counter_ && !--*counter_)`. We should also remember the code should be easy to read. We don't want to be the next "Perl"

Comment: Yes, we should be using the initializer lists in constructors - I'll fix that right now.

Comment: I'll disagree on `== nullptr` being unidiomatic, and personally favors avoiding implicit boolean conversions, even in boolean contexts.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I half agree with you. I find it situational weather you need the `== nullptr`. As long as the code is obvious (for me) to read I am happy.

Answer (score 5):

The unit test does not test the destructor and it should. I would suggest creating at least 1 function to implement the unit testing and call it from `main()`. To properly unit test you need to call every method implemented. It is quite possible the code does not work as you intend it to.

In `destroy_current()` what needs to be deleted is what `ptr_` points to, not the fields `ptr_` and `counter_`; it is possible that there is a memory leak here. It isn't clear why the `destroy_current()` function exists. The code in `destroy_current()` could easily be in the destructor itself.

The private variable `counter_` should not be a *pointer* to `std::size_t`: it should be a `std::size_t`. There is no reason to allocate the pointer; it will be allocated by the constructor by default.

You need to become comfortable with initialization lists in the constructors, as most of the constructors contain unnecessary code. Instead of the following:

```
    my_shared_ptr(T* ptr) {
        ptr_ = ptr;
        counter_ = new size_t(1);
    }

    my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& other) {
        destroy_current();
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        if (other.ptr_ != nullptr) {
            *counter_ += 1;
        }
    }

    my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& other) {
        ptr_ = other.ptr_;
        counter_ = other.counter_;
        
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
        other.counter_ = nullptr;
    }
```

The code could be:

```
    my_shared_ptr(T* ptr)
    : ptr_ { ptr }, counter_ { 1 }
    {
    }

    my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& other)
    : ptr_ { other.ptr }, counter_ { other.counter_ }
    {
        if (other.ptr_ != nullptr) {
            *counter_ += 1;
        }
    }

    my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& other)
    : ptr_ { other.ptr }, counter_ = { other_counter_ }
    {
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
        other.counter_ = nullptr;
    }
```

Use comments to identify the copy constructor and the move constructor. Because `counter_` is a pointer, the move constructor is keeping a link to the original `counter_` variable rather than updating the count.

Comment: I believe that `counter` is a pointer so that copies share the counter of the original.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I never liked destroy_current(), is this better?

Comment: Yes, that is better.

Comment: `The private variable counter_ should not be a pointer to std::size_t` . It needs to be a pointer.